# Accessing global variable defined inside a function

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to understand variable scopes in Javascript and a friend asked me this question. I could use some help here.

```
function abc(){
  var a = b = 10; // a is local, b is global variable. Right?
  c = 5; // c is global variable
}
d = 20; // d is global variable

console.log(b); // b is not defined error. Why? Isn't b a global variable?
console.log(c); // Again, Why is 'c not defined'.
```

I ran this code in chrome console. Shouldn't I expect 10 and 5 in console? It gives a 'b is not defined', 'c is not defined' error instead. Why does this happen if b, c are global variables? console.log(d) works just fine.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxckf4v5/2/).

Comment: If you don't call `abc`, `b` and `c` cannot exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this happen if `b`, `c` are global variables?

`b` and `c` are only created if you actually **call** `abc`. Merely *defining* the function does not magically execute its body.

```
function abc(){
  var a = b = 10; // a is local, b is global variable.
  c = 5; // c is global variable
}

// call abc to execute the statements inside the function
abc();

console.log(b); // 10
console.log(c); // 5
```

---

That said, implicitly creating global variables is not good still. Avoid globals if possible, and if not, explicitly declare them by assigning to the global object (`window` in browsers).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I had wrongly assumed that simply declaring a variable without the var keyword makes it accessible anywhere. We either call that function explicitly, or use self invoking functions. And yes, I avoid global variables as much as I can. I just wanted to bring it up here for my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

> **EDIT:**  This is why I love SO, you learn something knew even when you're a know it all and answer questions you clearly are not equipped
>   to answer. Thanks to @FelixKling's clarification I have updated this to reflect that `var`s

So there's a little bit of a terminology confusion going on here:

Javascript has *function level scope*: as `a` and `b` are declared inside the `function` block they are local to the `function` they were declared within and are constrained to the `function`'s scope.

Variables defined *outside* a function (or in a browser on the `window` object, in node on the `global` object), have `global`scope.

<s>So the `var` keyword doesn't actually have anything to do with `global` scope, scope is defined by where you declare a variable.</s>

Taking your example:

```
function abc(){
  var a = b = 10; //a is local, b is global (see @FelixKling's answer)
  c = 5; // c is global as it is not prefixed with the `var` keyword 
}
var d = 20; // d is global 


console.log(a); // logs "10" to the console
console.log(b); // b is not defined
console.log(c); // 'c not defined'.
console.log(d); // logs 20 to the console.
```

Comment: Variables declared inside the function block using `var` keyword are **local**

Comment: `b` and `c` are not declared. They are assigned to and JavaScript will make them global.

Comment: It does implicitly declare them, but in global scope (not very useful ;) )

Comment: Yeah I just editted my comment as I realised I hadnt finished that sentence :)